# how to find protractor uncle / cousin elements

Tags: protractor

I have the following HTML with several elements equal to this.  I need a way in protractor to locate this unique element (which I'm using by cssContainingText with '.list-group-item-heading', 'Analog output' because that is unique for this item) and then navigate up to the grandparent ('.ba-object-item') so I can get to the uncle ('.ba-value') to verify it displays 1 %

I will also need to eventually get to a cousin element ('.marengo-physical-output') to determine that the icon displayed is correct.

What is the best approach for traversing the DOM in this case?

```
<div class="ba-object-item">
  <div class="ba-text">
    <h5 class="list-group-item-heading text-primary">Analog output</h5>
    <span class="list-group-item-text">%R%'AO</span>
  </div>
  <div class="ba-value text-primary">1 %</div>
  <div class="ba-icon">
    <i class="icon icon-large marengo-physical-output" ng-reflect-klass="icon icon-large" ng-reflect-ng-class="marengo-physical-output"></i>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem's key point is to resolve how to locator the `<div class="ba-object-item">`,  you can try to find a `DIV` which includes a `H5` and the `H5`'s text is `Analog output` by XPath as following:

```
var baItem = element(
            by.xpath('//div[@class="ba-object-item"][./div/h5[text()="Analog output"]]'));

// or
var baItem = element(
            by.xpath('//div[@class="ba-object-item"][.//h5[text()="Analog output"]]'));

var baValue = baItem.element(by.css('div.ba-value'));

var baIcon = baItem.element(by.css('i.marengo-physical-output'))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to `protractor`. It is about `css` or `xPath`.
You could find a lot of useful information [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)